# Node.js Puppeteer problem with clicking button inside parent elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am using puppeteer library for scraping a website. 
I get all elements of exact class by:

```
let items = await page.$$("li.item");
for (let item of items) {
    let elementText = await page.evaluate(
        (element) => element.textContent,
    item);
    console.log(elementText );    
}
```

And I get all elements text. It works.
The problem is that I need to click a button that is inside these elements.
There is a box with `li.item` class and inside there is a button. I need to press each button inside each box. How can I do it?
I tried `element.children` or even console logging `element` but it shows only undefinded. What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Sowam,

```
let buttons = await page.$$("//li//button");
for (let button of buttons) {
    await button.click();   
}
```

Or

```
let buttons = await page.$$("//li.item//button");
for (let button of buttons) {
    await button.click();   
}
```

You click the button with page.click like this.